# Extract text of list

Tags: robotframework

Using Robotframework, I want to extract the texts of each element of a list contained in this html code :

```
<li class="ui-select-choices-group" id="ui-select-choices-6">
   <div class="divider ng-hide" ng-show="$select.isGrouped &amp;&amp; $index > 0"></div>
   <div ng-show="$select.isGrouped" class="ui-select-choices-group-label dropdown-header ng-binding ng-hide" ng-bind="$group.name"></div>
   <!-- ngRepeat: tenant in $select.items -->
   <!-- ngIf: $select.open -->
   <div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope active" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="tenant in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(tenant,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-6-0" style="">
       <span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
           <div ng-bind-html="tenant.name | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">RF_Account-1-</div>
       </span>
   </div>
   <!-- end ngIf: $select.open -->
   <!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in $select.items -->
   <!-- ngIf: $select.open -->
   <div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="tenant in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(tenant,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-6-1" style="">
       <span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
           <div ng-bind-html="tenant.name | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">RF_Account-2-</div>
       </span>
   </div>
   <!-- end ngIf: $select.open -->
   <!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in $select.items -->
   <!-- ngIf: $select.open -->
   <div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="tenant in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(tenant,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-6-2">
       <span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
           <div ng-bind-html="tenant.name | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">RF_Account-3-</div>
       </span>
   </div>
   <!-- end ngIf: $select.open -->
   <!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in $select.items -->
   <!-- ngIf: $select.open -->
   <div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="tenant in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(tenant,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-6-3">
       <span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
           <div ng-bind-html="tenant.name | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">RF_Account-4-</div>
       </span>
   </div>
   <!-- end ngIf: $select.open -->
   <!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in $select.items -->
   <!-- ngIf: $select.open -->
   <div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="tenant in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(tenant,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-6-4">
       <span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
           <div ng-bind-html="tenant.name | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">RF_Account-5-</div>
       </span>
   </div>
   <!-- end ngIf: $select.open -->
   <!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in $select.items -->
   <!-- ngIf: $select.open -->
   <div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="tenant in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(tenant,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-6-5">
       <span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
           <div ng-bind-html="tenant.name | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">RF_Account-6-</div>
       </span>
   </div>
   <!-- end ngIf: $select.open -->
   <!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in $select.items -->
</li>
```

My actually code in Robotframework is :

```
${maxTenant}    Get Element Count    //li[@class='ui-select-choices-group']//span
${accounts}    Create Dictionary
:FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    0    ${maxTenant}
\    ${elementId}    Get Element Attribute    //li[@class='ui-select-choices-group']//div[3+${i}]    id
\    ${elementName}    Get Text    ${elementId}
\    Set To Dictionary    ${accounts}    ${elementName}
Log Dictionary    ${accounts}
```

When I execute my script the ${accounts} dictionary is always empty.
Could you, please, help me understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, it works

```
    ${maxTenant}    Get Element Count    //li[@class='ui-select-choices-group']//span
    ${tenants}    Create List            
    :FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    0    ${maxTenant}
    \    ${elementName}    Get Text    //li[@class='ui-select-choices-group']//div[3+${i}]/*
    \    Append To List    ${tenants}    ${elementName}
    Log List    ${tenants}
```

I do not understand why. Can someone help me understand ?